# target._set is not a function(…) in aws-sdk module

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, image-uploading, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload base64 image to amazon using "aws-sdk" module, I am getting error as "target._set is not a function(…)". I am not able find out where I am doing wrong.

Please help me to resolve it.

Here is my code:

```
import 'aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk';
const AWS = window.AWS;

var configData = {
    "accessKeyId": "******",
    "secretAccessKey": "********",
    "region":"*****"
}

AWS.config.update(configData);

var buf = new Buffer(this.state.pic.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64');
var s3Bucket = new AWS.S3( { params: {Bucket: '****'} } );

var data = {
    Key: 'myImage.jpg',
    Body: buf,
    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
};

s3Bucket.putObject(data, function(err, data){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log('Error uploading data: ', data);
    } else {
      console.log('successfully uploaded the image!');
    //  console.log(profilePic);
      this.updateUser(profilePic, e);
    }
});
```